# Enabling javascript in webview causing page loading issue

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

I enabled javascript in my android webview. Now the page loads initially and then displays a blank white page. Disabling javascript causes the url to load fine.

```
class MainWebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() 
{
    lateinit var webview: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.tst_webview)
        webview = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        MyAsync("https://www.idiva.com/entertainment/bollywood/deepika-padukone-and-rishi-kapoor-to-star-in-hindi-adaptation-of-hollywood-film-the-intern/18006293").execute()
    }

    inner class MyAsync: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> 
    {
        val url: String
        constructor(url: String)
        {
            this.url = url
        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Document 
        {
            var document: Document? = null
            try 
            {
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
                document.getElementsByClass("header").remove()
                document.getElementsByClass("foo").remove()
            } 
            catch (e: IOException) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return document!!
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(document: Document?) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(document)
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, document.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "")
            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)

            webview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() 
            {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean 
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
                }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please add some code, efforts, and causes to your question. It helps peoples to solve your question.

Comment: Maybe the JS on that site is detecting that it's running in a WebView, and doesn't like it. It seems that the site owners are a bit picky about who views their content, because I get: "Hello, we are currently not providing access or use of our website/mobile application to our users in Europe."